# Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp

Tags: regex, validation, ip-address, ipv4, grep

I've been trying to get an efficient regex for IPv4 validation, but without much luck. It seemed at one point I had had it with `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?(\.|$)){4}`, but it produces some strange results:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.7
$ grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?(\.|$)){4}\b' <<< 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1
$ grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?(\.|$)){4}\b' <<< 192.168.1.255
192.168.1.255
$ grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?(\.|$)){4}\b' <<< 192.168.255.255
$ grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?(\.|$)){4}\b' <<< 192.168.1.2555
192.168.1.2555
```

I did a search to see if this had already been asked and answered, but other answers appear to simply show how to determine 4 groups of 1-3 numbers, or do not work for me.

Comment: Don't forget that A, and A.B, and A.B.C are valid forms of IP address as well as A.B.C.D. Seriously. Try `ping 2130706433` and `ping 127.1` for a giggle.

Comment: My variant online http://regexr.com/39hqf

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You've already got a working answer but just in case you are curious what was wrong with your original approach, the answer is that you need parentheses around your alternation otherwise the `(\.|$)` is only required if the number is less than 200.

```
'\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'
    ^                                    ^
```

Comment: this appears to also validate things like `192.168.1.1.1`

Comment: Should it be: `\b((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:(?<!\.)\b|\.)){4}`; i.e. so it ends with a word boundary rather than with the end of line?  Additionally here I've marked the non-capturing groups to avoid unwanted sub-matches.  NB: This still doesn't take into account @dty's comment as I'm not familiar with that form of IP; though he's correct that it seems valid.

Comment: You might want to try this instead:((1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])

Comment: This works well for non capturing - `\b(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b`

Comment: If I want to add mask also  the what will be the solution . Like  I have IPv4 `25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]/[0-9]` I want to add `/` then Mask. So what will I add to have mask ? Ex: __.__.__.__ / __. Total of 15 character .

Comment: Is `09.09.09.09` considered a valid IP? It also gets matched by this regex. But ping throws error message like `ping: cannot resolve 09.09.09.09: Unknown host`. I think it might be wise to reduce the matching to dot-decimal notation matching only. This [entry](https://superuser.com/questions/857603/are-ip-addresses-with-and-without-leading-zeroes-the-same) discusses on leading errors in IP addresses.

Comment: This thing also validate cases like as `192.168.1.36.424.3232.1.0.3.0`, `192.168.32.1.424`, `9999.166.166.166.166`, `http://192.168.1.41`, `.....0.....1.2.3.0`, `weird:10.0.0.0`.

Comment: Change pattern to `^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(\.|$)){4}\b` to address the zero-padding issue on single digits.

Comment: Don't stop here, @danail-gabenski 's answer below offer another regex handling more edge cases.

Comment: There is a small issue with it. I tried to fix it and here is the outcome: `(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{0,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))`

Answer (score 218):

**Best for Now (*43 chars*)**

`^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$`

This version shortens things by another 6 characters while not making use of the negative lookahead, which is not supported in some regex flavors.

**Newest, Shortest, Least Readable Version (*49 chars*)**

`^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$`

The `[0-9]` blocks can be substituted by `\d` in 2 places - makes it a bit less readable, but definitely shorter.

**Even Newer, even Shorter, Second least readable version (*55 chars*)**

`^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$`

This version looks for the 250-5 case, after that it cleverly ORs all the possible cases for `200-249` `100-199` `10-99` cases. Notice that the `|)` part is not a mistake, but actually ORs the last case for the 0-9 range. I've also omitted the `?:` non-capturing group part as we don't really care about the captured items, they would not be captured either way if we didn't have a full-match in the first place.

**Old and shorter version (less readable) (*63 chars*)**

`^(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$`

**Older (readable) version (*70 chars*)**

`^(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$`

It uses the negative lookahead `(?!)` to remove the case where the ip might end with a `.`

**Alternative answer, using some of the newer techniques (*71 chars*)**

`^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)$`

Useful in regex implementations where lookaheads are not supported

**Oldest answer (*115 chars*)**

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}
    (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])$
```

I think this is the most accurate and strict regex, it doesn't accept things like `000.021.01.0.` it seems like most other answers here do and require additional regex to reject cases similar to that one - i.e. `0` starting numbers and an ip that ends with a `.`

Comment: This is the only correct answer in this thread up to this date. The others miss such addresses as `0.0.0.0` or accept mixed octal/decimal notation like `033.033.33.033` or even allow 999.999.999.999. How about this regex which is 10 chars shorter than this answer: `(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`

Comment: Oops. Vicky also seems to have had supplied a correct one. His answer was downvoted, maybe because he did not explain why his was superior to the others. Upvoted his as well.

Comment: hey @anneb yeah you could shorten it a bit with {2} otherwise you just reversed the order of matching which is fine as well. The othe problem would be that you need the ^ at the beginning and $ at the end of the regex in order to not match anything that deviates from the regex.

Comment: As far as @vicky 's answer the problem is that it matches stuff like ..23.23 i.e. not sure why it's [0-9]? instead of just [0-9] for his last case. And again you do need the ^ and $ otherwise strings like 2555.100.232.10 are validated as correct, since it matches the last 55 from the 2555 number.

Comment: Error on my end . It accepts **192.168**, which it shouldn't.

Comment: @JohndelfMiñao not sure how you got it to accept 192.168 because it's just 2 things where we require {4}. I assume you wanted to edit your comment and that you made an error ?

Comment: Nope, I test it over and over again. It just accepts **192.168**.

Comment: @JohndelfMiñao hmm, I usually use regex101.com for checking my regular expressions. If you paste the regex in the top field and then in the test string field you type in "192.168." then select ECMAScript on the left it shouldn't highlight it for you. If you enter a valid ip v4 like 192.168.0.1 it should highlight it. Let me know.

Comment: It worked on the test but did not worked in my validation. Currently use the regex for my angular validation.

Comment: @JohndelfMiñao feel free to post a new question with your example and maybe me or someobdy else can help you figure it out - should be a pretty easy fix.

Comment: @tinmarino I reverted your edit because it allowed things like 192.168.000.1 which is not a valid address. Anyone that wishes to edit this answer, please comment first here in order to avoid problems like these - I usually reply pretty fast. Always looking for a shorter/better solution of course.

Comment: @DanailGabenski (and other) for memory, you solved it replacing last `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` by `1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]` because you don't like [leading 0](https://superuser.com/a/857618/759736). Thank again ! I'll keep your solution in my regex master luggage.

Comment: @tinmarino yes, the dot-decimal format that has become standard for ipv4, [although not officially accepted please look at the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation). Specifically point 3, where a draft was suggested but expired. A secondary reason for being so strict with validation is that when presented in the UI, ip's with non-decimal numbers like 023 instead of 23 make users thing this is a mistake/bug. It also leads to difficulties with verification/security as 023 needs to be converted to 23 to avoid duplicates, etc. Thanks for trying to make things better !

Comment: You can make it shorter by factoring out the `[0-9]` for the `2[0-4]`, `1`, and shorter cases.


`^(?:(25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$`

Comment: Thank you @ClaytonSingh ! I've gone ahead and made the change to the actual answer. I've also removed the non-capturing groups clause, which doesn't seem to affect the answer, but makes it a bit shorter, the answer is now aroud 48% of it's original length.

Comment: $ echo "192.168.1.1" | grep -E '^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$'  --  Did not work . Expected to match

Comment: @Talespin_Kit try -P instead of -E, I was targeting the JavaScript syntax, but seems to be compatible with the PCRE one.

Comment: In a case of ```hostname -I``` command this: ```hostname -I|perl -ne'print $& if $_=~/((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.|(?=\s)|$)){4}/'``` appears to work

Comment: @DanailGabenski beautiful Regex! But it still can be even shorter by using `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: @DanailGabenski I am new to REGEX and I am studying your regex solution. I understand the first part of your answer, but am having a hard time decoding the second part of you answer. For me as a newbie, can you please explain the (\.(?!$)|$)){4}$ portion of your "Even Newer, even Shorter, Second least readable version" solution? I understand that \. is the escape sequence for the dot to follow after the expression specified in the first part of your solution. Thank you

Comment: @Arsik36 hey, I would recommend plugging the regex in a site like regex101.com and select the JavaScript syntax on the left, then enter a sample IP to match in the lower box. Now if you hover over any part of the regex you pasted in the top most box, it should show you what it's trying to match on the right of your screen - it's color coded and everything.

The part you mentioned tries to match a DOT at the end if it's not the end of the line OR match the end of the line with no DOT beforehand. This works because we can have only 1 end of line and with {4} we require exactly 4 instances.

Comment: Hi @DanailGabenski I made an edit to show a shortened version of the original using some of the newer patterns. I did this for regex implementations that don't support lookaheads, like the one used in Terraform. Hope it's not an issue!

Comment: An additional pattern I'd like to add (asking permission first this time!) is one that includes the CIDR notation. Something like this long form: `^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])[.]){3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])[/](3[0-2]|[12][0-9]|[0-9])$` and this short form: `^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(\.(?!$)|$)){4}[/](3[0-2]|[12][0-9]|[0-9])$`. What do you think?

Comment: @Speeddymon I accepted the previous edit with some changes, see if those work for Terraform. I would say that the CIDR version is welcomed as well, just be sure to add one with the lookahead and one without it - also try to use the newest/shortest one for both of them. I'll do some testing on the one I accepted and the CIDR one to see if they are correct all the time. Thanks for contributing !

Comment: Thanks! The `\d` syntax doesn't work in Terraform but seeing as this post is generally related to regex, and not specific to Terraform, I think it can stay with that syntax.

Comment: @Speeddymon looking at the Terraform documentation it does seem like \d and \D are supported so it should work. I'll take a look at the CIDR specs and try to add your contribution in a separate section below.

Comment: Hmm, I tried but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Here's the regex I could come up with for the CIDR -> ^(((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(\.|)){4}((?<!\.)\/)(3[0-2]|[12]\d|\d))$ but I don't think it's entirely correct as depending on the CIDR value the allowed values for the IP change drastically. This would be a case for code doing the check if the IP is correct based on the CIDR - you would need like 32 different regexes at that point, so it might be optimal to just use the ipv4 regex and then check if the 4 resulting numbers are in the correct ranges.


I was looking at https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex and \d is there.

Comment: Any idea how I could modify the shortest regex to also include ports as in **IP:PORT**? I added `:\d{1,4}` or `:([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])` at the end of `^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$` (before the $) but that didn't work.

Comment: @Vinayak actually it's not that simple to deal with the port, but here is a sample regex similar to the one for the ip -> ^((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))$

At this point it might be easier to split by : and then check if the resulting string is the same as a number - can't start with 0s and has to be between 0 and 65535 (including).

Comment: @Vinayak Here is the shortest regex I could come up with that matches a ipv4 address and port (1-65535).

`^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(\.(?!$)|:(([1-5]\d|[1-9])\d{0,3}|6(5(5(3[0-5]$|[0-2])|[0-4]\d)|[0-4]\d\d)\d?)$)){4}$`

Match numbers 1-65535
`^(([1-5]\d|[1-9])\d{0,3}|6(5(5(3[0-5]$|[0-2])|[0-4]\d)|[0-4]\d\d)\d?)$`

I am using a different approach since we have so many digits to match here by breaking into two primary cases. First numbers under 60000 using `([1-5]\d|[1-9])\d{0,3}`. In the second case we deal with the numbers under 65535, by breaking off each digit at a time.

Comment: You can replace "(\.(?!$)|$)" with "\.?\b" to make it shorter.

Comment: Thanks @liudongmiao I noticed your comment, but spent some time testing it and then forgot all about it - it's updated now !

Comment: When I tested this one
^(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$
I found the $ at the end was redundant. I think this is because it is already accounted for in the preceding group.

Comment: @JamesFricker yeah I think that's correct, just use the latest and greatest though it's simpler and more efficient than this variant.

Comment: Wow @DanailGabenski I just came back to this after over a year to find an even shorter one which doesn't use lookaheads! AWESOME! Impressive!

Comment: Here is the one that I do use:  `^(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?1)$` .  It has fewer steps to run, so should be faster.

Comment: @Jotne yeah this one seems to work for PCRE/2 but not any of the other flavors on regex101.com. It's also not shorter than the 43 character answer, as far as efficiency it matches group2 3 times, then matches group1 once which is pretty cool, but not sure if faster.

Comment: You can change `(?1)` with `\1 `to make it work on more regex

Comment: @Jotne it doesn't match any IPs with the \1 change and is still not valid for other syntaxes as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Fl1BM9/1

Comment: Shortening `[0-9]` to `\d` is a bad idea because `\d` also covers non-Latin digits such as those represented in Arabic, Hebrew, Chinese, etc.

Comment: @BalusC this is an interesting point - do you have some examples of this that you can share, perhaps on regex101.com, please do select the ECMAScript Flavor on the left - but I guess if you find some flavors work while others don't let's just add them to the issue so people can keep them in mind. I tried personally with different language numbers to replicate \d matching them and it didn't work at all for some reason.

Answer (score 118):

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

**Accept**:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.255
255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0
1.1.1.01        # This is an invalid IP address!
```

**Reject**:

```
30.168.1.255.1
127.1
192.168.1.256
-1.2.3.4
1.1.1.1.
3...3
```

Try online with unit tests: https://www.debuggex.com/r/-EDZOqxTxhiTncN6/1

Comment: what about "3...3" ip address ? 3...3 is accepted using this regex

Comment: What about 1.1.1.01? Is it considered a valid IPv4 address? Thanks.

Comment: this regexp 1.1.1.01 consider as VALID IPv4 address. Online unit tests https://www.debuggex.com/r/-EDZOqxTxhiTncN6/1

Comment: by the way `^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}$` get same result https://www.debuggex.com/r/mz_-0dEm3wseIKqK, pretty similar with @Mark Byers answer

Comment: @PriteshAcharya Works fine over here.

Comment: @Sllouyssgort your shorter version does not work. It recognizes 1.1.1.1. (note the trailing dot) as a valid IP.

Comment: It is not very valid :) I edited your code in this way `(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{0,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))` and it works better and faster

Comment: false positive 1.1.1.00

Comment: most invalid IP address are matched. Check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/dcc76935fb40).

Answer (score 16):

IPv4 address (accurate capture)
Matches 0.0.0.0 through 255.255.255.255, but does capture invalid addresses such as 1.1.000.1
Use this regex to match IP numbers with accuracy.
Each of the 4 numbers is stored into a capturing group, so you can access them for further processing.

```
\b
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
\b
```

taken from JGsoft RegexBuddy library

Edit: this `(\.|$)` part seems weird

Comment: Nice! I did a more efficient modification of that which seems to work: `"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$){4}\b` -- thanks!

Comment: @MatthieuCartier Your efficient regex pattern didn't work for me,

Comment: 255.255.255.000 is not a valid IP

Answer (score 12):

I think many people reading this post will be looking for simpler regular expressions, even if they match some technically invalid IP addresses. (And, as noted elsewhere, regex probably isn't the right tool for properly validating an IP address anyway.)

Remove `^` and, where applicable, replace `$` with `\b`, if you don't want to match the beginning/end of the line.

**Basic Regular Expression (BRE) (tested on GNU grep, GNU sed, and vim):**

```
/^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+$/
```

**Extended Regular Expression (ERE):**

```
/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
```

or:

```
/^([0-9]+(\.|$)){4}/
```

**Perl-compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) (tested on Perl 5.18):**

```
/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

or:

```
/^(\d+(\.|$)){4}/
```

**Ruby (tested on Ruby 2.1):**

Although supposed to be PCRE, Ruby for whatever reason allowed this regex not allowed by Perl 5.18:

```
/^(\d+[\.$]){4}/
```

My tests for all these are online [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/ipv4_regex/blob/master/test.sh).

Comment: Your: `/^(\d+[\.$]){4}/` is for `5.5.5.5.` not `5.5.5.5`

Answer (score 9):

I was in search of something similar for IPv4 addresses - a regex that also stopped commonly used private ip addresses from being validated (192.168.x.y, 10.x.y.z, 172.16.x.y) so used negative look aheads to accomplish this:

```
(?!(10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])\.|192\.168\.).*)
(?!255\.255\.255\.255)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9])
(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[1]\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}
```

(These should be on one line of course, formatted for readability purposes on 3 separate lines)
[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pgJ4BdM6bGNIjHh-)

It may not be optimised for speed, but works well when only looking for 'real' internet addresses.

Things that will (and should) fail:

```
0.1.2.3         (0.0.0.0/8 is reserved for some broadcasts)
10.1.2.3        (10.0.0.0/8 is considered private)
172.16.1.2      (172.16.0.0/12 is considered private)
172.31.1.2      (same as previous, but near the end of that range)
192.168.1.2     (192.168.0.0/16 is considered private)
255.255.255.255 (reserved broadcast is not an IP)
.2.3.4
1.2.3.
1.2.3.256
1.2.256.4
1.256.3.4
256.2.3.4
1.2.3.4.5
1..3.4
```

IPs that will (and should) work:

```
1.0.1.0         (China)
8.8.8.8         (Google DNS in USA)
100.1.2.3       (USA)
172.15.1.2      (USA)
172.32.1.2      (USA)
192.167.1.2     (Italy)
```

Provided in case anybody else is looking for validating 'Internet IP addresses not including the common private addresses'

Answer (score 6):

'''
This code works for me, and is as simple as that.

Here I have taken the value of ip and I am trying to match it with regex.

```
ip="25.255.45.67"    

op=re.match('(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)',ip)

if ((int(op.group(1))<=255) and (int(op.group(2))<=255) and int(op.group(3))<=255) and (int(op.group(4))<=255)):

print("valid ip")

else:

print("Not valid")
```

Above condition checks if the value exceeds 255 for all the 4 octets then it is not a valid. But before applying the condition we have to convert them into integer since the value is in a string.

group(0) prints the matched output, Whereas group(1) prints the first matched value and here it is "25" and so on.
'''

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you could spend some words on why your answer should solve the OP issue, would be great. Only-code answers are generally bad answers as they don't help fellow coders understand what they had done wrong.

Comment: Use proper indenting in your code to make it readable for the users

Answer (score 6):

Here is a better one with passing/failing IPs attached

```
/^((?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/
```

Accepts

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.255
255.255.255.255
10.1.1.1
0.0.0.0
```

Rejects

```
1.1.1.01
30.168.1.255.1
127.1
192.168.1.256
-1.2.3.4
1.1.1.1.
3...3
192.168.1.099
```

Answer (score 5):

Above answers are valid but what if the ip address is not at the end of line and is in between text.. This regex will even work on that.

code: `'\b((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.)){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\b'`

input text file:

```
ip address 0.0.0.0 asfasf
 sad sa 255.255.255.255 cvjnzx
zxckjzbxk  999.999.999.999 jshbczxcbx
sjaasbfj 192.168.0.1 asdkjaksb
oyo 123241.24121.1234.3423 yo
yo 0000.0000.0000.0000 y
aw1a.21asd2.21ad.21d2
yo 254.254.254.254 y0
172.24.1.210 asfjas
200.200.200.200
000.000.000.000
007.08.09.210
010.10.30.110
```

output text:

```
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.255
192.168.0.1
254.254.254.254
172.24.1.210
200.200.200.200
```

Answer (score 5):

```
/^(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.){3}(?1)$/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPyOJk/1)

Comment: note: this works in Perl, but no Java :-(

Answer (score 4):

I managed to construct a regex from all other answers.

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]?)){3}
```

Comment: As per the IEEE 802.x ethernet standard the IP validation is  
IP range 0.x.x.x  >>> should not  be allowed - invalid IP.
#1.The IP range starts from 1.x.x.x to 126.x.x.x  >>>> can be allowed to configure. #2.IP range 127.x.x.x  >>>> should not  be allowed - invalid IP.
#3.IP range 128.x.x.x to 223.x.x.x  >> can be allowed to configure.
the better way to handle is suggested as below:
^(22[0-3]|2[0-1][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$

Answer (score 4):

This is a little longer than some but this is what I use to match IPv4 addresses. Simple with no compromises.

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$
```

Answer (score 4):

For number from 0 to 255 I use this regex:

```
(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))
```

Above regex will match integer number from 0 to 255, but not match 256.

So for IPv4 I use this regex:

```
^(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))((\.(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))){3})$
```

It is in this structure: `^(N)((\.(N)){3})$` where N is the regex used to match number from 0 to 255.
This regex will match IP like below:

```
0.0.0.0
192.168.1.2
```

but not those below:

```
10.1.0.256
1.2.3.
127.0.1-2.3
```

For IPv4 CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing) I use this regex:

```
^(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))((\.(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))){3})\/(([0-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[0-2]))$
```

It is in this structure: `^(N)((\.(N)){3})\/M$` where N is the regex used to match number from 0 to 255, and M is the regex used to match number from 0 to 32.
This regex will match CIDR like below:

```
0.0.0.0/0
192.168.1.2/32
```

but not those below:

```
10.1.0.256/16
1.2.3./24
127.0.0.1/33
```

And for list of IPv4 CIDR like `"10.0.0.0/16", "192.168.1.1/32"` I use this regex:

```
^("(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))((\.(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))){3})\/(([0-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[0-2]))")((,([ ]*)("(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))((\.(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))){3})\/(([0-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[0-2]))"))*)$
```

It is in this structure: `^(“C”)((,([ ]*)(“C”))*)$` where C is the regex used to match CIDR (like 0.0.0.0/0).
This regex will match list of CIDR like below:

```
“10.0.0.0/16”,”192.168.1.2/32”, “1.2.3.4/32”
```

but not those below:

```
“10.0.0.0/16” 192.168.1.2/32 “1.2.3.4/32”
```

Maybe it might get shorter but for me it is easy to understand so fine by me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Could you please elaborate a bit on what the different regex' are doing (in particular the last one)?

Answer (score 3):

```
(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2})))
```

Test to find matches in text,
https://regex101.com/r/9CcMEN/2

Following are the rules defining the valid combinations in each number of an IP address:

- Any one- or two-digit number.
- Any three-digit number beginning with `1`.
- Any three-digit number beginning with `2` if the second digit is `0`
  through `4`.
- Any three-digit number beginning with `25` if the third digit is `0`
  through `5`.

Let'start with `(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))\.)`, a set of four nested subexpressions, and we’ll look at them in reverse order. `(\d{1,2})` matches any one- or two-digit number or numbers `0` through `99`. `(1\d{2})` matches any three-digit number starting with `1` (`1` followed by any two digits), or numbers `100` through `199`. `(2[0-4]\d)` matches numbers `200` through `249`. `(25[0-5])` matches numbers `250` through `255`. Each of these subexpressions is enclosed within another subexpression with an `|` between each (so that one of the four subexpressions has to match, not all). After the range of numbers comes `\.` to match `.`, and then the entire series (all the number options plus `\.`) is enclosed into yet another subexpression and repeated three times using `{3}`. Finally, the range of numbers is repeated (this time without the trailing `\.`) to match the final IP address number. By restricting each of the four numbers to values between `0` and `255`, this pattern can indeed match valid IP addresses and reject invalid addresses.

> Excerpt From: [Ben Forta. “Learning Regular Expressions.”](http://www.forta.com/books/0134757068/)

---

If neither a character is wanted at the beginning of IP address nor at the end, `^` and `$` metacharacters ought to be used, respectively.

```
^(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))\.){3}(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d{2})|(\d{1,2})))$
```

Test to find matches in text,
https://regex101.com/r/uAP31A/1

Answer (score 3):

## Find a valid ip address in the text is a very difficult problem

---

I have a regexp, that match (extract) valid ip addresses from strings in text files.

### my regexp

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\b
```

- `\b` word boundary
- `(?:` - means start non capturing group
- `^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.)` - string must start with first right octet with dot char

  - (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|`[1-9]`) - find first right octet - (firt octet can not start with - 0)
- `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){2}` -  find next right two octets with dot string
- `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\b` - string must end with right fourth octet (now zero char is allowed)

But this ip regexp has a minority false positive matches:

https://regexr.com/69dk7

[image: regexp for mostly right match for ip addresses]

**Find or extract valid ip address from text file with only regexp is impossible. Without checking another conditions you always get false positive matches.**

## Solution

---

I write **one liner perl** for extract ip addresses from text files. It has this conditions:

- when the ip address is at the beginning of the line, the next char is one or multiple whitespace char (space, tab, new line...)
- when ip address is at end of line, the new line is next char and before ip address is one or multiple whitespace chars
- in middle of text - before and after ip address is one or multiple whitespace chars

The consequence is that perl not match strings like `https://84.25.74.125` and another URI strings. Or ip addres at the end of line with dot char at the end. **But it find any valid ip address in the text.**

**perl one liner solution:**

```
$ cat ip.txt | perl -lane 'use warnings; use strict; for my $i (@F){if ($i =~/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])$/) { print $i; } }'
36.42.84.233
158.22.45.0
36.84.84.233
12.0.5.4
1.25.45.36
255.3.6.5
4.255.2.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.5
126.0.0.1
```

testing text file:

```
$ cat ip.txt
36.42.84.233 stop 158.22.45.0 and 56.32.58.2.
25.36.84.84abc and abc2.4.8.2 is error.
1.2.3.4_
But false positive is 2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2 or 1.1.1.1.1
http://23.54.212.1:80
https://89.35.248.1/abc
36.84.84.233 was 25.36.58.4/abc/xyz&158.133.26.4&another_var
and 42.27.0.1:8333 in http://212.158.45.2:26
0.25.14.15 ip can not start with zero
2.3.0
abc 12.0.5.4
1.25.45.36
12.05.2.5
256.1.2.5
255.3.6.5
4.255.2.1
4.256.5.6
127.0.0.1 is localhost.
this ip 127.0.0.5 is not localhost
126.0.0.1
```

## Appendix

---

For people from another planets for whom the strings `2130706433`, `127.1`, `24.005.04.52` is a valid ip address I have a message: **Try to find a solution yourself!!!**

Answer (score 2):

IPv4 address is a very complicated thing.

**Note**: Indentation and lining are only for illustration purposes and do not exist in the real RegEx.

```
\b(
  ((
    (2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])
  |
    0[Xx]0*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}
  |
    0+[1-3]?[0-9]{1,2}
  )\.){1,3}
  (
    (2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])
  |
    0[Xx]0*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}
  |
    0+[1-3]?[0-9]{1,2}
  )
|
  (
    [1-3][0-9]{1,9}
  |
    [1-9][0-9]{,8}
  |
    (4([0-1][0-9]{8}
      |2([0-8][0-9]{7}
        |9([0-3][0-9]{6}
          |4([0-8][0-9]{5}
            |9([0-5][0-9]{4}
              |6([0-6][0-9]{3}
                |7([0-1][0-9]{2}
                  |2([0-8][0-9]{1}
                    |9([0-5]
    ))))))))))
  )
|
  0[Xx]0*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}
|
  0+[1-3]?[0-7]{,10}
)\b
```

These IPv4 addresses are validated by the above RegEx.

```
127.0.0.1
2130706433
0x7F000001
017700000001
0x7F.0.0.01 # Mixed hex/dec/oct
000000000017700000001 # Have as many leading zeros as you want
0x0000000000007F000001 # Same as above
127.1
127.0.1
```

These are rejected.

```
256.0.0.1
192.168.1.099 # 099 is not a valid number
4294967296 # UINT32_MAX + 1
0x100000000
020000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Valid regex for IPV4 address for Java

```
^((\\d|[1-9]\\d|[0-1]\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])[\\.]){3}(\\d|[1-9]\\d|[0-1]\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$
```

Comment: I've tried some from this post but none of those did pass code signal test but this one passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Considering some variants suggested, `\d` and `\b` may not be supported. Hence, just in case:

#### IPv4 address

```perl
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?|0)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?|0)$
```

Test: https://debuggex.com/r/izHiog3KkYztRMSJ

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

The shortest pattern is not necessarily the most efficient. I prefer

```
^(?:\b\.?(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){4}$
```

which is a good tradeoff between pattern-length and efficiency.

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xYQi8u/2)

This pattern works by use of a [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and making the dot [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). The *word boundary* will still require a dot between each 0-255. Placement of `\b` disallows a dot at the [`^` start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Certainly by use of [`(` capturing `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead of [`(?:` non-capturing `)` groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) four characters can be spared but why *capture* anything without reason? No part gets reused or would be extracted.

The only reason that makes sense would be, if *non-capturing groups* are not supported.

---

Without validating 0-255 and allowing *any* one to three digits: [`^(?:\b\.?\d{1,3}){4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/C9y2G0/2)

Answer (score 1):

With subnet mask :

```
^$|([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\
.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\
.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\
.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])
((/([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it a bit simpler and shorter.

> `^(([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$`

If you are looking for java/kotlin:

> `^(([01]?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$`

If someone wants to know how it works here is the explanation. It's really so simple. Just give it a try :p :

```
 1. ^.....$: '^' is the starting and '$' is the ending.

 2. (): These are called a group. You can think of like "if" condition groups.

 3. |: 'Or' condition - as same as most of the programming languages.

 4. [01]?\d{1,2}: '[01]' indicates one of the number between 0 and 1. '?' means '[01]' is optional. '\d' is for any digit between 0-9 and '{1,2}' indicates the length can be between 1 and 2. So here the number can be 0-199.

 5. 2[0-4]\d: '2' is just plain 2. '[0-4]' means a number between 0 to 4. '\d' is for any digit between 0-9. So here the number can be 200-249.

 6. 25[0-5]: '25' is just plain 25. '[0-5]' means a number between 0 to 5. So here the number can be 250-255.

 7. \.: It's just plan '.'(dot) for separating the numbers.

 8. {3}: It means the exact 3 repetition of the previous group inside '()'.

 9. ([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]): Totally same as point 2-6
```

Mathematically it is like:

```
(0-199 OR 200-249 OR 250-255).{Repeat exactly 3 times}(0-199 OR 200-249 OR 250-255)
```

So, as you can see normally this is the pattern for the IP addresses. I hope it helps to understand Regular Expression a bit. :p

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it a bit simpler and shorter.

> ^(([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$

If you are looking for java/kotlin:

> ^(([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$

If someone wants to know how it works here is the explanation. It's really so simple. Just give it a try :p :

```
 1. ^.....$: '^' is the starting and '$' is the ending.

 2. (): These are called a group. You can think of like "if" condition groups.

 3. |: 'Or' condition - as same as most of the programming languages.

 4. [01]?\d{1,2}: '[01]' indicates one of the number between 0 and 1. '?' means '[01]' is optional. '\d' is for any digit between 0-9 and '{1,2}' indicates the length can be between 1 and 2. So here the number can be 0-199.

 5. 2[0-4]\d: '2' is just plain 2. '[0-4]' means a number between 0 to 4. '\d' is for any digit between 0-9. So here the number can be 200-249.

 6. 25[0-5]: '25' is just plain 25. '[0-5]' means a number between 0 to 5. So here the number can be 250-255.

 7. \.: It's just plan '.'(dot) for separating the numbers.

 8. {3}: It means the exact 3 repetition of the previous group inside '()'.

 9. ([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]): Totally same as point 2-6
```

Mathematically it is like:

```
(0-199 OR 200-249 OR 250-255).{Repeat exactly 3 times}(0-199 OR 200-249 OR 250-255)
```

So, as you can see normally this is the pattern for the IP addresses. I hope it helps to understand Regular Expression a bit. :p

Answer (score 1):

To validate any IP address in the valid range 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 can be written in very simple form as below.

```
((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

Answer (score 1):

don't reinvent the wheel ;)

the best way is to use well written and tested library

`npm @sideway/address` has 6M weekly downloads

```js
import { ipRegex } from "@sideway/address";

const { regex } = ipRegex({ version: ['ipv4'], cidr: 'forbidden' });
```

the regex for ipv4 without cidr is:

`/^(?:(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))$/`

unit tested on:

```js
const validIPv4sWithoutCidr = [
  '0.0.0.0',
  '255.255.255.255',
  '127.0.0.1',
  '192.168.2.1',
  '0.0.0.3',
  '0.0.0.7',
  '0.0.0.15',
  '0.0.0.31',
  '0.0.0.63',
  '0.0.0.127',
  '01.020.030.100',
  '0.0.0.0',
  '00.00.00.00',
  '000.000.000.000'
];
```

but you can easily with (without) options match other versions and be sure it covers all possibilities

```js
import { ipRegex } from "@sideway/address";

const { regex } = ipRegex();
```

`/^(?:(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\/(?:\d|[1-2]\d|3[0-2]))?|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|::(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,1}[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4})?::)(?:\/(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-8]))?|v[\dA-Fa-f]+\.[\w-\.~!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:]+(?:\/(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1[01]\d|12[0-8]))?)$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
    const char*ipv4_regexp = "\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\."
    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\."
    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\."
    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b";
```

I adapted the regular expression taken from JGsoft RegexBuddy library to C language (regcomp/regexec) and I found out it works but there's a little problem in some OS like Linux.
That regular expression accepts ipv4 address like 192.168.100.009 where 009 in Linux is considered an octal value so the address is not the one you thought.
I changed that regular expression as follow:

```
    const char* ipv4_regex = "\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\."
           "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\."
           "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\."
           "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\b";
```

using that regular expressione now  192.168.100.009 is not a valid ipv4 address while 192.168.100.9 is ok.

I modified a regular expression for multicast address too and it is the following:

```
    const char* mcast_ipv4_regex = "\\b(22[4-9]|23[0-9])\\."
                        "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\."
                        "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]?)\\."
                        "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\b";
```

I think you have to adapt the regular expression to the language you're using to develop your application

I put an example in java:

```
    package utility;

    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class NetworkUtility {

        private static String ipv4RegExp = "\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]?\\d?)\\b";

        private static String ipv4MulticastRegExp = "2(?:2[4-9]|3\\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d\\d|[1-9]\\d?|0)){3}";

        public NetworkUtility() {

        }

        public static boolean isIpv4Address(String address) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ipv4RegExp);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(address);

            return matcher.matches();
        }

        public static boolean isIpv4MulticastAddress(String address) {
             Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ipv4MulticastRegExp);
             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(address);

             return matcher.matches();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-bash-3.2$ echo "191.191.191.39" | egrep 
  '(^|[^0-9])((2([6-9]|5[0-5]?|[0-4][0-9]?)?|1([0-9][0-9]?)?|[3-9][0-9]?|0)\.{3}
     (2([6-9]|5[0-5]?|[0-4][0-9]?)?|1([0-9][0-9]?)?|[3-9][0-9]?|0)($|[^0-9])'
```

`>> 191.191.191.39`

(This is a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that matches the entire addr space (including broadcasts, etc.) and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is the shortest.

```
^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).){3}([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this sample very useful, furthermore it allows different ipv4 notations.

sample code using python:

```
    def is_valid_ipv4(ip4):
    """Validates IPv4 addresses.
    """
    import re
    pattern = re.compile(r"""
        ^
        (?:
          # Dotted variants:
          (?:
            # Decimal 1-255 (no leading 0's)
            [3-9]\d?|2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4]?\d)?|1\d{0,2}
          |
            0x0*[0-9a-f]{1,2}  # Hexadecimal 0x0 - 0xFF (possible leading 0's)
          |
            0+[1-3]?[0-7]{0,2} # Octal 0 - 0377 (possible leading 0's)
          )
          (?:                  # Repeat 0-3 times, separated by a dot
            \.
            (?:
              [3-9]\d?|2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4]?\d)?|1\d{0,2}
            |
              0x0*[0-9a-f]{1,2}
            |
              0+[1-3]?[0-7]{0,2}
            )
          ){0,3}
        |
          0x0*[0-9a-f]{1,8}    # Hexadecimal notation, 0x0 - 0xffffffff
        |
          0+[0-3]?[0-7]{0,10}  # Octal notation, 0 - 037777777777
        |
          # Decimal notation, 1-4294967295:
          429496729[0-5]|42949672[0-8]\d|4294967[01]\d\d|429496[0-6]\d{3}|
          42949[0-5]\d{4}|4294[0-8]\d{5}|429[0-3]\d{6}|42[0-8]\d{7}|
          4[01]\d{8}|[1-3]\d{0,9}|[4-9]\d{0,8}
        )
        $
    """, re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
    return pattern.match(ip4) <> None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((\.|^)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?|0$)){4}
```

This regex will not accept
08.8.8.8 or 8.08.8.8 or 8.8.08.8 or 8.8.8.08

Comment: this one misses for example 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0

Comment: ^((\.|^)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?|[0-9]?|0))((\.|^)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?|0)){2}.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?|0)$)

Comment: It is correct to reject leading zeros, according to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Finds a valid IP addresses as long as the IP is wrapped around any character other than digits (behind or ahead the IP). 4 Backreferences created: $+{first}.$+{second}.$+{third}.$+{forth}

```
Find String:
#any valid IP address
(?<IP>(?<![\d])(?<first>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<second>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<third>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<forth>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))(?![\d]))
#only valid private IP address RFC1918
(?<IP>(?<![\d])(:?(:?(?<first>10)[\.](?<second>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5])))|(:?(?<first>172)[\.](?<second>(:?1[6-9])|(:?2[0-9])|(:?3[0-1])))|(:?(?<first>192)[\.](?<second>168)))[\.](?<third>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<forth>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))(?![\d]))

Notepad++ Replace String Option 1: Replaces the whole IP (NO Change):
$+{IP}

Notepad++ Replace String Option 2: Replaces the whole IP octect by octect (NO Change)
$+{first}.$+{second}.$+{third}.$+{forth}

Notepad++ Replace String Option 3: Replaces the whole IP octect by octect (replace 3rd octect value with 0)
$+{first}.$+{second}.0.$+{forth}
NOTE: The above will match any valid IP including 255.255.255.255 for example and change it to 255.255.0.255 which is wrong and not very useful of course.
```

Replacing portion of each octect with an actual value however you can build your own find and replace which is actual useful to ammend IPs in text files:

```
for example replace the first octect group of the original Find regex above:
(?<first>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))
with
(?<first>10)

and
(?<second>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))
with
(?<second>216)
and you are now matching addresses starting with first octect 192 only

Find on notepad++:
(?<IP>(?<![\d])(?<first>10)[\.](?<second>216)[\.](?<third>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<forth>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))(?![\d]))
```

You could still perform Replace using back-referece groups in the exact same fashion as before.

You can get an idea of how the above matched below:

```
cat ipv4_validation_test.txt
Full Match:
0.0.0.1
12.108.1.34
192.168.1.1
10.249.24.212
10.216.1.212
192.168.1.255
255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0


Partial Match (IP Extraction from line)
30.168.1.0.1
-1.2.3.4
sfds10.216.24.23kgfd
da11.15.112.255adfdsfds
sfds10.216.24.23kgfd


NO Match
1.1.1.01
3...3
127.1.
192.168.1..
192.168.1.256
da11.15.112.2554adfdsfds
da311.15.112.255adfdsfds
```

Using grep you can see the results below:

```
From grep:
grep -oP '(?<IP>(?<![\d])(?<first>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<second>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<third>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<forth>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))(?![\d]))' ipv4_validation_test.txt
0.0.0.1
12.108.1.34
192.168.1.1
10.249.24.212
10.216.1.212
192.168.1.255
255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0
30.168.1.0
1.2.3.4
10.216.24.23
11.15.112.255
10.216.24.23


grep -P '(?<IP>(?<![\d])(?<first>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<second>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<third>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<forth>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))(?![\d]))' ipv4_validation_test.txt
0.0.0.1
12.108.1.34
192.168.1.1
10.249.24.212
10.216.1.212
192.168.1.255
255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0
30.168.1.0.1
-1.2.3.4
sfds10.216.24.23kgfd
da11.15.112.255adfdsfds
sfds10.216.24.23kgfd


#matching ip addresses starting with 10.216
grep -oP '(?<IP>(?<![\d])(?<first>10)[\.](?<second>216)[\.](?<third>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))[\.](?<forth>(:?\d)|(:?[1-9]\d)|(:?1\d{2})|(:?2[0-4]\d)|(:?25[0-5]))(?![\d]))' ipv4_validation_test.txt
10.216.1.212
10.216.24.23
10.216.24.23
```

Answer (score 0):

> `^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.)){3}+((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))$`

---

Above will be regex for the ip address like:
221.234.000.112
also for 221.234.0.112, 221.24.03.112, 221.234.0.1

---

You can imagine all kind of address as above

Answer (score 0):

I would use PCRE and the `define` keyword:

```
/^
 ((?&byte))\.((?&byte))\.((?&byte))\.((?&byte))$
 (?(DEFINE)
     (?<byte>25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?))
/gmx
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IB7j48/2

The reason of this is to avoid repeating the `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` pattern four times. Other solutions such as the one below work well, but it does not capture each group as it would be requested by many.

```
/^((\d+?)(\.|$)){4}/
```

The only other way to have 4 capture groups is to repeat the pattern four times:

```
/^(?<one>\d+)\.(?<two>\d+)\.(?<three>\d+)\.(?<four>\d+)$/
```

Capturing a ipv4 in perl is therefore very easy

```
$ echo "Hey this is my IP address 138.131.254.8, bye!" | \
  perl -ne 'print "[$1, $2, $3, $4]" if \
    /\b((?&byte))\.((?&byte))\.((?&byte))\.((?&byte))
     (?(DEFINE)
        \b(?<byte>25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))
    /x'

[138, 131, 254, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most precise, straightforward and compact IPv4 regexp I can imagine is

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)$
```

But what about the performance/efficiency of ... Sorry I don't know, who cares?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.(2[0-5][0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]))\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ip address can be from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

(((0|1)?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){3}((0|1)?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$

(0|1)?[0-9][0-9]? - checking value from 0 to 199
2[0-4][0-9]- checking value from 200 to 249
25[0-5]- checking value from 250 to 255
[.] --> represent verify . character 
{3} --> will match exactly 3
$ --> end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the regex expression to validate the IP-Address.

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{0,1})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{0,1})
```

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W6_-JDQjsjhuPTLW)

Answer (score 0):

This one matches only valid IPs (no prepended 0's, but it will match octets from 0-255 regardless of their 'function' [ie reserved, private, etc]) and allows for inline matching, where there may be spaces before and/or after the IP, or when using CIDR notation.

```
grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)'

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< '10.0.1.2'
10.0.1.2

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< 'ip address 10.0.1.2'
ip address 10.0.1.2

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< 'ip address 10.0.1.2 255.255.255.255'
ip address 10.0.1.2 255.255.255.255

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< 'ip address 10.0.1.2/32'
ip address 10.0.1.2/32

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< 'ip address 10.0.1.2.32'
$

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< 'ip address10.0.1.2'
$

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< '10.0.1.256'
$

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< '0.0.0.0'
0.0.0.0

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< '255.255.255.255'
255.255.255.255

$ grep -E '(^| )((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($| |/)' <<< '255.255.255.256'
$
```

Of course, in cases where the IP is inline, you can use grep option "-o" and your preference of whitespace trimmer if you just want the whole IP and nothing but the IP.

For those of us using python, the equivalent is roughly:

```
>>> ipv4_regex = re.compile(r'(^| )((?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])($| |/)')
>>> ipv4_regex.search('ip address 10.1.2.3/32')
<re.Match object; span=(10, 20), match=' 10.1.2.3/'>
```

If you're picky (lazy) like me, you probably would prefer to use grouping to get the whole IP and nothing but the IP, or the CIDR and nothing but the CIDR or some combination thereof. We can use [(?P) syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to name our groups for easier reference.

```
>>> ipv4_regex = re.compile(r'(?:^| )(?P<address>((?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[1-9]?\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))(?P<slash>/)?(?(slash)(?P<cidr>[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-2]))(?:$| )')
>>> match = ipv4_regex.search('ip address 10.0.1.2/32')
>>> match.group('address')
'10.0.1.2'
>>> match.group('cidr')
'32'
>>> "".join((match.group('address'), match.group('slash'), match.group('cidr')))
'10.0.1.2/32'
```

There's ways of not using just regex, of course. Here's some conditions that you could check (this one doesn't find inline, just validates the passed address is valid).

First check is that each char in the address is a digit or a '.'

Next checking that there are exactly 3 '.'

The next two checks check that each octet is between 0 and 255.

And the last check is that no octets are prepended with a '0'

```
def validate_ipv4_address(address):
    return all(re.match('\.|\d', c) for c in address) \
        and address.count('.') == 3 \
        and all(0 <= int(octet) <= 255 for octet in address.split('.')) \
        and all((len(bin(int(octet))) <= 10 for octet in address.split('.'))) \
        and all(len(octet) == 1 or d[0] != '0' for octet in address.split('.'))


>>> validate_ipv4_address('255.255.255.255')
True
>>> validate_ipv4_address('10.0.0.1')
True
>>> validate_ipv4_address('01.01.01.01')
False
>>> validate_ipv4_address('123.456.789.0')
False
>>> validate_ipv4_address('0.0.0.0')
True
>>> validate_ipv4_address('-1.0.0.0')
False
>>> validate_ipv4_address('1.1.1.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in validate_ipv4_address
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <genexpr>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> validate_ipv4_address('.1.1.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in validate_ipv4_address
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <genexpr>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> validate_ipv4_address('1..1.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in validate_ipv4_address
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <genexpr>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

(bitwise, each octet should be 8 bits or less, but each is prepended with '0b')

```
>>> bin(0)
'0b0'
>>> len(bin(0))
3
>>> bin(255)
'0b11111111'
>>> len(bin(256))
11
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw very bad regexes in this page.. so i came with my own:

```
\b((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\b
```

Explanation:

```
num-group = (0-9|10-99|100-199|200-249|250-255)
<border> + { <num-group> + <dot-cahracter> }x3 + <num-group> + <border>
```

Here you can verify how it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/5m1Vhw/1)

Answer (score 0):

My [extended] approach → regexp for space-separated IP addresses:

`((((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\\.(?=\\d)|(?!\\d))){4})( (?!$)|$))+`

Uses PCRE look-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ^(127|10).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"

Answer (score 0):

This pattern unclude 52 symbols and accept cuncks started with zero.

```
/^(?:(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.|$)){4}\b$/
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution here:

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$
```

This regex will match:

```
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.255
123.123.123.123
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
```

But it will NOT match:

```
192.168.1.01
256.256.256.256
01.01.01.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try using [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

```
const validateIPAddress = (ipAddress) => {
  try {
    new URL(`http://${ipAddress}`);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Wrong IP Address");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is regex works for me:
`"\<((([1-9]|1[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1-9]|1[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]))\>"`

Answer (score -3):

`^\\s*[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]\\s*`

Comment: This would match `0987654.3.2.1` too.

Answer (score -3):

```
String zeroTo255 = "([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|(0|1)[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";

it can contain single digit i.e ([0-9]);  
It can contain two digits i.e ([0-9][0-9]); 
range is (099 to 199)i.e((0|1)[0-9][0-9]); 
range is (200 - 249) i.e (2[0-9][0-9]) ; 
range is (250-255) i.e(25[0-5]);
```