# Regex to match an IP address

Tags: php, regex, string, ip, preg-match

I am newbie with regex and  I want to use `preg_match` function to find if a string is an IP address.

For example,

```
$string = "10.0.0.1";
preg_match($regex, $string);
```

should return true. So, what `$regex` should be?

Comment: Did you give a try to Google first? http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/ipaccurate.html

Comment: `45.56.78.888` is not an IP address.

Comment: @bazmegakapa yeah I just realize, I wrote it randomly:D but you got the point I think;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Comment: [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284147/608639)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Don't use a regex when you don't need to :)

```
$valid = filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

Though if you really do want a regex...

```
$valid = preg_match('/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\z/', $string);
```

The regex however will only validate the format, the max for any octet is the max for an unsigned byte, or `255`.

This is why IPv6 is necessary - an IPv4 address is only 32bits long and the internet is popular :)

Comment: Does filter_var work for ::1 as IP?

Comment: for good IP regex > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165922/regex-for-ip-address/20270082#20270082

Comment: \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b

Comment: Or `$valid = (filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false);` if you strictly want a boolean back.

Comment: @DesignerGuy Just prefixing it with `(bool)` would be better I reckon.

Comment: @alex — True. Especially in this case it's probably fine. You'd only have to be careful in a variation of something like this where you could end up with a value that passes the filter but is still false-y.

Comment: @DesignerGuy It's been a while since I wrote some PHP, but if it returns a string, isn't the empty string the only false-y value? I wonder if that is ever a *valid match*.

Comment: @alex — The string `'0'` will be treated as false.

Comment: @alex : Then 999.999.999.999 will also be valid IP then!!??

Comment: That is fairly simple but noone would want Wrong IP address. Please consider adding valid IP address Regex too as the answer. See people come on this page considering they would get Regex for **Valid** IP address, but they dont get that Regex. Thanks

Comment: @PratikCJoshi At the expense of a complicated regex. You would be best to take each part as a matched group and validate its range then.

Comment: Please edit the answer and explain as it would make sense.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi it's already there

Comment: Where is 255 limit in regex?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi The answer is given in PHP, to use ´filter_var()´. How would sample code in PHP validating the parts make sense? I'm sure people don't have a problem implementing the condition ´$num <= 255´.

Comment: better: /^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$/

Comment: @ollazarev Nice one, I don't know why that repetition in my regex didn't trigger my *there must be a better way* refactoring.

Answer (score 9):

```
/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/
```

should do for your example (which does contain a string that is *not* an IP address). And of course, it's only an IPv4 address.

Comment: @alex : Then 999.999.999.999 will also be valid IP then!!??

Comment: @PratikCJoshi: The original question (which has been edited years after my answer) asked for a regex that would match any sequence of four dot-separated numbers of up to 3 characters each...

Comment: That is fairly simple but noone would want Wrong IP address. Please consider adding valid IP address Regex too as the answer. See people come on this page considering they would get Regex for **Valid** IP address, but they dont get that Regex. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/
```

This will check for the Perfect Range including if a Range is Higher than 255 from any of 4.