# Regular Expression (.Net Regex) for IPv6 and IPv4

Tags: c#, devexpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex for IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165922/regex-for-ip-address)

There is a regular expression match IPv6 **AND** IPv4 ?
Or, just IPv6 ?

For validation mask in a DevExpress UI control.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165922/regex-for-ip-address/9165988#9165988

Comment: Thanks, i need IPv6 regular expression as String

Comment: Maybe this: (([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4})([:|.])){2,7}([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4})

Answer (score 5):

I know you asked for a Regular Expression but you might want to consider using the `System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse` method instead.

Comment: how he use parse in regex field of control?

Comment: thanks, but i need it for validation mask in a DevExpress UI control. its a String.

Comment: The TryParse method accepts a string and returns a bool, it uses an out param to return the IPAddress object.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx

Comment: You don't need to use the out value and it will parse either v4 or v6.

Comment: i see, but in my scenario i need a String of Regular Expression in purpose to set it into a String Property of a UI Control as a Validation Mask. there is no input until its pass the validation, so i cant use System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse method

Answer (score 2):

The IP4 one can look like
"(0?0?[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])(\.(0?0?[0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])){2}(\.(0?0?[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]))"

this allows for 0's too, eg 010.000.000.001 .. (cos someone in our place thought it smart to do it)

Answer (score 0):

it's really long regex =) first row for ip4, rest is ip6

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|
((\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,6}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,6}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}\Z)|
(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,7}|:):\Z)|
(\A:(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7}\Z)|
(\A((([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6})(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})\Z)|
(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,1}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,4}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,3}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,2}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,5}|:):(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)|
(\A:(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,5}:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\Z)
)
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason it's recognize just IPv4.