# PHP - Check if a string contains an IP address

Tags: php, regex, dns

I have a string like this:

"(01:42 PM)76.124.231.190 William: Hello?"

I need a regex to remove the IP address like this:

```
preg_replace($regex, "", "(01:42 PM)76.124.231.190 William: Hello?")
// --> "(01:42 PM) William: Hello?"
```

I've seen this: [Regex to match an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865817/regex-to-match-an-ip-address/5865849#5865849), but that checks if the string **is** an IP, not if it contains it.

Also, it don't have to be perfect, 999.99.999.999 is ok for simplicity.

Comment: Have you tried wildcard before and after? Like `.*?(original_regex_here).*?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At it's simplest, this regex should work.

```
preg_replace('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', "", "(01:42 PM)76.124.231.190 William: Hello?")
```

Comment: for good IP regex > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165922/regex-for-ip-address/20270082#20270082

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have the same string length before the IP each time you could just use a substring in php and select out the ip address. Just use the substr

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are trying to pull out a specific IP out of a string. You don't need regex for that.

This can be done easily with [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$myStringWithIP = '(01:42 PM)76.124.231.190 William: Hello?';
str_replace('76.124.231.190', '', $myStringWithIP);

#$myStringWithIP now equals '(01:42 PM) William: Hello?'
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but str_replace won't remove anything in the string that looks like an IP. Only the one you specify in the code.

Comment: And that's what I don't want.

Comment: You are very belligerent. In your question you said: `I need a regex to remove the IP address like this:` That isn't true. The IP address can be removed using `str_replace`.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the title then.