# How to match IPv4 addresses

Tags: regex, posix, ip-address

I am trying to have my regex match the following:

```
169.254.0.0-169.254.254.255
```

Could anyone please help how can I achieve this.

so far I have this:

```
169\.254\.([1-9]{1,2}|[1-9]{1,2}[1-4])
```

but it would also pick up 169.254.255.1 which should not be one of the matches.

Please help!

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284147/608639)

Answer (score 6):

This is the regex I use for general IP validation:

```
(([0-9](?!\d)|[1-9][0-9](?!\d)|1[0-9]{2}(?!\d)|2[0-4][0-9](?!\d)|25[0-5](?!\d))[.]?){4}
```

Breakdown:

```
1.`[0-9](?!\d)`       -> Any Number 0 through 9 (The `(?!\d)` makes sure it only grabs stand alone digits)
2.`|[1-9][0-9](?!\d)` -> Or any number 10-99 (The `(?!\d)` makes sure it only grabs double digit entries)
3.`|1[0-9]{2}`        -> Or any number 100-199
4.`|2[0-4][0-9]`      -> Or any number 200-249
5.`|25[0-5]`          -> Or any number 250-255
6.`[.]?`              -> With or without a `.`
7.`{4}`               -> Lines 1-6 exactly 4 times
```

This hasn't failed my yet for IP address validation.

For your specific case, this should do it:

```
(169\.254\.)((([0-9](?!\d)|[1-9][0-9](?!\d)|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])[.])(([0-9](?!\d)|[1-9][0-9](?!\d)|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])))
```

This is very long because I couldn't figure out how to get 169.254.(0-254).255 to check without getting 169.254.255.1 to fail

Edit: Fixed due to comments

Comment: Does not enforce the dots between octets - i.e. it erroneously matches: `1111111111`, `100.1111111`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I adjusted the 2nd one for his case to force the `.` between octets, but for the primary one I don't want to force it.  For the main one, it's a trade off, because I would have to nearly double the size of the regex to force the `.` between octets.  I found it easier to verify `###.###.###.###` format before checking the validity of the IP address itself than to check for the IP address and the `.` at the same time.  In my environment, I have much more control over the input, and I'm mainly check to make sure a `523` didn't get entered into a spread sheet instead of a `253`.

Comment: Actually, I though about it, and realized there was no reason I couldn't do the negative lookahead after each set. Now it should correctly force the dot between octets.  I checked it quickly, and it correctly rejects the two examples you gave.

Answer (score 2):

the regex `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])` matches 0-254.

see [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) for more discussion

Comment: its matching 169.254.25 for 169.254.255.1. any thoughts?

Comment: I would repeat the test twice, with the final digit on the 2nd section changed to 5 for the 255 match: `169\.254\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) `

Answer (score 1):

I've written an article that provides regular expressions for all the components of a generic URI (as defined in  [RFC3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986))

See: [Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

One of the components of a generic URI is an IPv4 address. Here is the free-spacing mode Python version from that article:

```py
re_python_rfc3986_IPv4address = re.compile(r""" ^
    # RFC-3986 URI component:  IPv4address
    (?: (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?) \.){3}  # (dec-octet "."){3}
        (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)         # dec-octet "."
    $ """, re.VERBOSE)
```

And the un-commented JavaScript version:

```js
var re_js_rfc3986_IPv4address = /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
```