# pattern for matching ipv4 address in Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I need to find if a string (in Java) contains IPv4 address (it can be present anywhere).
I used the following line but it fails :

```
if (token.matches(".[0-9]{1,3}/..[0-9]{1,3}/..[0-9]{1,3}/..[0-9]{1,3}") == true)
```

what can be wrong here.

Comment: You can get some [help](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/) here .

Comment: you don't need to say == true either, that's redundant

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp

Comment: What do you mean by "present anywhere"?

Comment: @fge the IP address could be anywhere in the string . As in not at the begginning or end.

Comment: @damo I tried this 
token.matches("\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.|$)){4}\b")
but does not work.

Comment: I found one pattern
"(([0-9](?!\\d)|[1-9][0-9](?!\\d)|1[0-9]{2}(?!\\d)|2[0-4][0-9](?!\\d)|25[0-5](?!\\d))[.]?){4}" but how can I make sure this pattern can occur anywhere in the string ?

Comment: I got it . I added ".*" at the end and beginning of the above pattern and it works now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a pure regex for that is possible, but there are tools to check the validity of an IP address already.

Supposing the string is a list of tokens separated by spaces you can do that:

```
// Crude check
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\.\\d+){3}");

public boolean containsIPAddress(final String input) 
{
    for (final String candidate: input.split("\\s+")) {
        if (!PATTERN.matcher(candidate).matches())
            continue;
        try {
            InetAddress.getByName(candidate);
            return true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException ignored) {
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Using Guava, it is even easier:

```
private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(' ');

public boolean containsIPAddress(final String input) 
{
    for (final String candidate: SPLITTER.split(input)) {
        if (InetAddresses.isInetAddress(candidate))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks fge but the problem is the IP address may be attach with a prefix like say /23 or /32 . So I need a pattern which can match anywhere in the String

Answer (score 0):

The direction of slash is wrong. This is not the file system path where you can safely use forward slash instead of backslash. This is regular expression, so you have to use real back slash `\` and duplicate it because you are writing java code: `\\`

So, here is the expression:

`token.matches("(?:\\d\\.){1,3}\\d{1,3}")`

Comment: I tried it but does not work.