# Regex IF condition

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking for a way to filter new IP-Addresses in my host file.
I created a script which updates my host file every time when I call it with data from the matrix enterprise manager. It works fine. But I have to find a solution that only 10.XX.XX.XX or 172.XX.XX.XX addresses are allowed to update.

```
Param(
  $newHost = $args[0],
  $newIP = $args[1]
)

$SourceFile = "hosts"
$Match = "$newHost"

(Get-Content $SourceFile) | % {if ($_ -notmatch $Match) {$_}} | Set-Content $SourceFile

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

$tab = [char]9
$enter = $newIP + $tab + $newHost

if ($newIP XXXX)  #--> here should be a regex if condition... no clue how it works..

$enter | Add-Content -Path hosts
```

Comment: /10\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d|172\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d

Comment: Can you assist me with the if condition?

Comment: If (`$newIP -Match "^(10|172)\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){3}$") {...`, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp (especially when you want to be strict).

Comment: Thank you. $reg = "^10.|^172."

if($newIP -match $reg){ 
$enter | Add-Content -Path hosts
}

Comment: @OliZ. That expression is incorrect. An unescaped `.` matches any character except newlines in a regular expression.

Comment: "^10\.|^172\." is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily convoluted and doesn't make proper use of the features PowerShell provides.

- Don't assign `$args[...]` to parameters. That's not how [parameter handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) in PowerShell works. Make the parameters mandatory instead.
- `% {if ($_ -notmatch $Match) {$_}}` is better phrased as `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $Match}`.
- If `$Match` is an FQDN the dots might cause false positives (because they match any character, not just literal dots). Either escape `$Match` (`[regex]::Escape($Match)`) or use the `-notlike` operator instead.
- PowerShell has an escape sequence for tabs (`` `t ``). No need to define a variable with a value of `[char]9`.
- Putting variables in a double-quoted string (`"$var1$var2"`) is often more readable than string concatenation (`$var1 + $var2`).

Change your code to something like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Hostname,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$IPAddress
)

$SourceFile = 'hosts'

(Get-Content $SourceFile) |
  Where-Object { $_ -notlike "*$Hostname*" } |
  Set-Content $SourceFile

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

if ($IPAddress -match '^(10|172)\.') {
  "$IPAddress`t$Hostname" | Add-Content $SourceFile
}
```

If you want to avoid writing the output file multiple times, you could collect the data read in a variable, and then write that variable and the new record in one go:

```
$hosts = @(Get-Content $SourceFile) | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "*$Hostname*" })

if ($IPAddress -match '^(10|172)\.') {
  $hosts += "$IPAddress`t$Hostname"
}

$hosts | Set-Content $SourceFile
```

You could further optimize your script by doing the check via [parameter validation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/11/validate-powershell-parameters-before-running-the-script/), so you don't need an `if` condition in the function body in the first place, e.g. like this:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Hostname,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidatePattern('^(10|172)\.')]
  [string]$IPAddress
)
```

or like this:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Hostname,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateScript({$_ -match '^(10|172)\.' -and [bool][ipaddress]$_})]
  [string]$IPAddress
)
```

Comment: You're missing a square bracket in the param block before **$IPAddress** , but I'm not allowed to make a one-character edit. ;-)

Comment: @CharlieJoynt Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the comments above use regex to validate the entire IPv4 address. If you are confident that the IP address you are checking is valid, then you can use `"^(10|172)\."` to verify just the first octet of the address as per your question:

```
if($newIP -match "^(10|172)\.") { ... }
```

If you do want to validate the whole address, there is an alternative way to do this by converting **$newIP** to a `[System.Net.IPAddress]` type. If this fails the result will be nothing (null), which is implicitly false, so the following gives you a true/false check that a string is a valid IP address:

```
[bool]($newIP -as [System.Net.IPAddress])
```

You could use this to validate the input to the function written by Ansgar:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateScript({[bool]($_ -as [System.Net.IPAddress]})
[string]$IPAddress
```

Comment: Concerning the validation: just`[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Net.IPAddress]$IPAddress` is better and results in the following standard error when the type is incorrect: **Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'IPAddress'. Cannot convert value "Test" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "An invalid IP address was specified."**

Comment: In this particular case (since the OP wants to allow only 2 specific /8 subnets, and  the address is going to a text file anyway) I would consider a string parameter with a `ValidatePattern()` clause the better option.

Comment: Ooh. `ValidatePattern()` is new to me. I think I learn more by answering questions than asking them. :-)