# How can I make regex to search for ipv4 address only?

Tags: regex, linux

How can I make regex to search for ipv4 address only.
when I am doing

```
grep -E '([0-9]\.){1,3}[0-9]\b filename
```

It is showing group with five octets also.

Comment: Do you want to extract matched substrings or the whole lines with the matching pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp)

Comment: Try `grep -P '(?<!\d\.|\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?!\.?\d)' filename`. What a shame, none of the solutions in [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp) work for the current scenario, though one of them is close.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can be done with a POSIX regex, thus I'd rather suggest a PCRE solution:

```
grep -P '(?<!\d\.|\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?!\.?\d)' filename
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!\d\.|\d)` - a location that is not immediately preceded with  a digit and a dot or just a digit
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` - three occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?!\.?\d)` - a location that is not immediately followed with  an optional dot and then a digit.

To make the pattern a bit more precises, replace the octet pattern (`\d{1,3}`) with `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`.