# Regex for matching IPv4 addresses

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Let's say I have 3 strings:

```
str1 = 'Hello my name is Ben and my IP address is 127.1.1.1'
str2 = 'Hello my name is Folks and my IP address is 1.2.3.4.5'
str3 = 'Hello all, ip addresses: 1.2.3.4.5, 127.1.2.1, 127.2.1.2'
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
find_ip(str1) #['127.1.1.1']
find_ip(str2) #[]
find_ip(str2) #['127.1.2.1', '127.2.1.2']
```

1. Criteria:

   - IM addresses with the following form 'x.x.x.x'
   - Regex should be **1 group**.
   - The number of digits doesn't matter (111.111.111.111) is good.

P.S The solution of [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp) does **NOT** answer this question.

Comment: You sure you'll never need to handle IPv6 addresses?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I won't need to handle IPv6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Regex matches IPs from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`, not preceded or followed by a period or a digit:

```
(?<![\.\d])(?:[0-9]\.|1\d?\d?\.|2[0-5]?[0-5]?\.){3}(?:[0-9]|1\d?\d?|2[0-5]?[0-5]?)(?![\.\d])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UUCywc/3

Edit: to avoid matching IPs with a negative number as the first digit (eg. `-127.2.1.2`), and to allow IPs like `001.001.001.001`, then use:

```
(?<![-\.\d])(?:0{0,2}?[0-9]\.|1\d?\d?\.|2[0-5]?[0-5]?\.){3}(?:0{0,2}?[0-9]|1\d?\d?|2[0-5]?[0-5]?)(?![\.\d])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UUCywc/6

Full Python implementation:

```
import re

str1 = 'Hello my name is Ben and my IP address is 127.1.1.1'
str2 = 'Hello my name is Folks and my IP address is 1.2.3.4.5'
str3 = 'Hello all, ip addresses: 1.2.3.4.5, 127.1.2.1, 127.2.1.2'

def find_ip(test_str):
    regex = re.compile(r"(?<![-\.\d])(?:0{0,2}?[0-9]\.|1\d?\d?\.|2[0-5]?[0-5]?\.){3}(?:0{0,2}?[0-9]|1\d?\d?|2[0-5]?[0-5]?)(?![\.\d])")
    return regex.findall(test_str)

print(find_ip(str1)) #['127.1.1.1']
print(find_ip(str2)) #[]
print(find_ip(str3)) #['127.1.2.1', '127.2.1.2']
```

Comment: These fail to match if the number two digits and is > 25.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below regular expression. It will get ip addresses that starts with 127 followed by 3 sets of numbers with dots.

```
re.findall( r'127+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', str1 )
re.findall( r'127+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', str2 )
re.findall( r'127+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', str3 )
```

Result:

```
['127.1.1.1']
[]
['127.1.2.1', '127.2.1.2']
```