# how to apply regex on hive table for IP address filtering?

Tags: regex, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have hive table:

```
       department     ip 
          A           10.192.168.2
          B           172.16.0.1
          A           10.192.168.23
          B           172.16.0.24
                      10.192.168.56
```

I want to use regex on ip column so that I can fetch only records which is in ip range like below

output :

```
       department     ip 
          A           10.192.168.2
          A           10.192.168.23
                      10.192.168.56
```

Here ip range of department A is from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

Regex is not a tool for this task because for strict checking you need complex regexp that is not readable. Read also this: [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp). Strict regex looks too complex. Apply simple regexp if possible like this:

```
where IP rlike '^10\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$'
```

Or if you need strict checking then split IP address by `.` and check each octet for the range, like this, will look simpler than strict regex (not tested):

```
 select department, ip 
 from
 (
 select department, ip, split(ip, '\\.') i
   from your_table t
 )s where  i[0]=10 
      and (i[1] between 0 and 255 )
      and (i[2] between 0 and 255 )
      and (i[3] between 0 and 255 );
```

In python you can apply more elegant solution and check network mask/prefix like this: [checking-if-ipv4-address-in-network-python](https://medium.com/@sadatnazrul/checking-if-ipv4-address-in-network-python-af61a54d714d)