# How to get rid of None Type in my output - I only want to select valid IP addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, findall

Any idea how to not include anything with None?  I am trying to just pull in IP addresses at this point, but I don’t want to include empty elements.

My API Response

```
[{'name': '', 'serial': 'Q2KN-xxxx-438Z', 'mac': '0c:8d:db:c3:ad:c8', 'networkId': 'L_6575255xxx96096977', 'model': 'MX64', 'address': '', 'lat': 38.4180951010362, 'lng': -92.098531723022, 'notes': '', 'tags': '', 'wan1Ip': '47.134.13.195', 'wan2Ip': None}, {'name': '', 'serial': 'Q2PD-xxx-QQ9Y', 'mac': '0c:8d:db:dc:ed:f6', 'networkId': 'L_657525545596096977', 'model': 'MR33', 'address': '', 'lat': 38.4180951010362, 'lng': -92.098531723022, 'notes': '', 'tags': '', 'lanIp': '10.0.0.214'}]
```

Iterating through elements and selecting certain fields

```
response = requests.request("GET", url + id + '/devices', headers=headers)
data = response.json()
for item in data:
  keys = [item.get(x) for x in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip']]
  print(*keys, sep="\n", file=sys.stdout)
```

My output is:

```
47.134.13.195
MX64
None
None
None
MR33
10.0.0.214
None
```

My desired output is:

```
47.134.13.195
10.0.0.214
```

I’ve tried adding a re.findall for ip addresses, but not sure that’s going to work for me.  I’ve also tried to add operators for `not in None` and several other things.

re.findall(“(?:[\d]{1,3}).(?:[\d]{1,3}).(?:[\d]{1,3}).(?:[\d]{1,3})?“,string2 )

Update
I've changed my line to 
`keys = [item.get(x) for x in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip', '{}']if x in item]`

Obviously, I still have non IP addresses in my output, but I can select the elements that have IP addresses only.  My main issue was None.  I will also try some of the other suggestions.

Comment: Your if clause should be `if x in item and item[x]` I also prefer to manipulate IP addresses as IP addresses [rather than strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search each key ipv4 with regex(https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284410/6250402) and check key is None with `item.get(x) or ''`

```
import re

myRegex = re.compile(r'\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b')
# data here

for item in data:

    keys = [item.get(x) for x in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip'] if myRegex.search(item.get(x) or '')]
    print(*keys, sep="\n", file=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Thank you Hongarc - do you know if there is any benefit of doing it one way or the other?  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to your list comprehension to check to see if key `x` is in `item`.

```py
for item in data:
  keys = [item.get(x) for x in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip'] if x in item]
  print(*keys, sep="\n", file=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Wow!  Could it be that simple?  

So, I added that line in and it remove most of the None output.  Oddly enough I had one None still in my output, which doesn't make any sense to me.

```47.13.135.195
MX64
None
MR33
10.0.0.214```

Comment: Oh - it's not from the element data - it's the actual element wan2Ip doesn't exist in my second list.

Comment: I added '{}' - that should work, correct?
```keys = [item.get(x) for x in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip' '{}']if x in item]```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this condition to the end of your list comprehension:

```py
keys = [item.get(x) for x in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip'] if item.get(x) is not None]
```

The output will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
    >> data = response.json()
    >> keys = [x.get(key) for key in ['wan1Ip', 'model', 'lanIp', 'wan2Ip'] for x in data if x.get(key)]
    >> print(keys)
    >> ['47.134.13.195', 'MX64', 'MR33', '10.0.0.214']
```