# regex extract all valid IPv4 from string

Tags: regex

From a similar string below I would like to extract only the valid IPv4 addresses

```
233.444.444.222 , 127.0.0.1 , 127.0.0.0.1 , 192.168.1.1 , 812.1.1.1.1
```

where I have some valid ip addresses and some random numbers separated by "."
Using the below:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
```

I extract also 127.0.0.0 and 1.1.1.1 which are not good.
Any suggestion please?

KR
dk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookarounds to avoid matching an IP-address led or trailed by a dot:

```
(?<!\.)\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b(?!\.)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6yHTnY/1

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Tx!