# Part of the string is being picked as ip address

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

ip = "10.20.30.40 this is an ip. 20.30.40.50.100 this is not ip"

def checkip(ip):
    pat = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
    ips = re.findall(pat, ip)
    print(ips)
    
checkip(ip)
```

output:
['10.20.30.40', '20.30.40.50'] --> here second one is not an ip. but it it picking part of the string.

When I tried the pattern as "^\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+$" I'm not getting empty list.

I don't want second string to be picked, as it is not an ip address. I want to grep only ip address.
Not sure what I'm missing and how to debug this. Can someone please help here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last line of your question? “*Second one is not a string*” What does this exactly mean in this context? It is in fact a string, no?

Comment: @esqew I have a feeling that he ment "Second one is not valid ip adress string", not sure tho...

Comment: @esqew I said that second one is not an ip address. ip address contains only four comma separated octets. As second string means "20.30.40.50.100" which is having 5 octets. I want to ignore that.

Comment: @TDiblik yes you are right. Thanks for adding the comment

Comment: "*I said that second one is not an ip address*" Yes, you did earlier in your question. But the last line here literally says "*Second one is not a string*", can you explain that or edit it to be a bit more clear on what you intended to convey here?

Answer (score 1):

If you're reasonably certain the IP addresses you'd like to extract from the broader `ip` string will be preceded and proceeded by whitespace characters (as in your example) *or* appear at the beginning/end of the broader string, you can use the following pattern to match them:

```
((?<=\s)|^)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)((?=\s)|$)
```

<sup>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Kr3CcW/1/) | H/T to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969006/269970) for the pattern to only match "valid" addresses</sup>

If you need additional assurance that the extracted IP or IPs are strictly *valid* according to the specification, you can use a module like [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) to validate they are spec-compliant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got some clue from your comment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for responding.

I couldn't find solution with the above patterns. But I found it myself. The following is working fine. I can extract all the ip like strings then later I can validate them separately.

pat = "\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\S+"

it working fine. I'm getting the following output.

['10.20.30.40', '20.30.40.50.100']