# Nginx reverse proxy to server that's specified in the path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx reverse proxy location setup like so:

```
location /192.168.0.10 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.10/;
}

location /192.168.0.11 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.11/;
}

location /192.168.0.12 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.12/;
}

location /192.168.0.13 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.13/;
}

location /192.168.0.14 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.14/;
}

location /192.168.0.15 {.....
```

This structure repeats about 96 times so that we can have a reverse proxy to each one. Is there a way to simplify it so that there is only one structure and that the IP in the location's path magically just appears in the proxy_pass directive? Because this is becoming a pain to manage as we add and remove servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following regex matching location should work:

```
location ~ ^/(?<proxy>192\.168\.0\.(?:10|11|12|13|14|15|...))(?:/(?<path>.*))?$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://$proxy/$path;
}
```

You can additionally optimize that non-capturing group `(?:10|11|12|13|14|15|...)`, for example to match any number from `10` to `105` it can be written as `(?:10[0-5]|[1-9]\d)`.

**Update 1**

As requested by OP, PCRE regex for any IPv4 address with strict checking (for matching only correct IPv4 addresses from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`, adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969006/7121513) answer) can be written as

```
location ~ "^/(?<proxy>(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d))(?:/(?<path>.*))?$" {
    ...
}
```

Due to the curly brackets usage regex pattern must be enclosed in double quotes.

**Update 2**

Previous solutions won't preserve the request query string, more correct solution to keep all the request query arguments is to use `proxy_pass http://$proxy/$path$is_args$args` directive:

```
location ~ "^/(?<proxy>(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d))(?:/(?<path>.*))?$" {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass    http://$proxy/$path$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. The server numbers is actually not important. The IP range also doesn't have to be dynamic. I struggle to understand the Nginx Regex flavour, so how would it look to make it even more dynamic? To basically catch any IP address.

Comment: I got it working thanks! I just used the following regex (?<proxy>[^/]+) for the proxy part. Then it caches anything I put in the first part of the path

Comment: Yours `[^/]+` will match **any** string at all. See the update for regex example matching only correct IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Found an error (query string won't be proxied), check an update to the answer.