# add line to file if matched in sed regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I want to check in a file if the word "range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100" , if the word range exists in the line then I want to add another line "ip address dhcp" that should be above the line "range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100" as a result such as :

```
"range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100" as a result i get : 
"ip address dhcp"
"range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100"
```

I tried with this regular expression: `"sed -r /s/([[:space:]]*)/range/l\ip address dhcp"` but did not work for me !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you want `sed '/range 0000\.00000 90000/i ip address dhcp' file`?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: It did not work. I don't want it to be like that, but that e.g.: range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100 the result:

ip address dhcp
range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.100

Thank you for help

Comment: Then `sed -E '/range ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/i\ip address dhcp' file`? See https://ideone.com/oGgULX

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```sh
sed -E '/range ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/i\ip address dhcp' file
```

Or, a bit more precise:

```sh
sed -E '/range ((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)([^0-9]|$)/i\ip address dhcp' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/oGgULX).

See [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp) for more IP address patterns if you need to adjust this pattern part.

Also, see the [`sed` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#compact):

> `i\`
> *text*
> insert *text* before a line.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. but i changed the regx ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3} in ([[:space:]]*).

Comment: @AhmedAsakra Just suit yourself, there are a lot of such patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/range/{print "ip address dhcp"} 1' file
```