# Clean repetitiveness in re.search() string

Tags: python-re

I wanted to know if my `re.search` string, which is repetitive, could be cleaned up.
The code: `re.search(r"^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"`

As you can see, the line `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` is being used 4 times, and I feel like it could be shortened by assigning it to a variable? But I have no clue on how to use variables in this string.

If you could, please do explain the code as well, which would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you want to get? show an output so we can make a useful regex for you.

Comment: I actually have a bit of other code. The only thing I want is to replace the string and make it cleaner, nothing else. But since you asked, it asks the user for an IPv4 Address (e.g: 127.36.24.35) and then "validates" it (makes sure the numbers are in the range of 0 and 255, inclusive). Then it returns True or False.

Comment: ^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$ Try this.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind posting it as a separate answer, and explain it, It would be appreciated and I can also mark it as the correct answer if it works!

Comment: Also, I feel the code works like this:
`((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}` checks for any number between 0 and 255, followed by a period 3 times, and `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` just checks for a number between 0 and 255.
And I believe the `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` checks for either 000 - 099 or 100 - 199 optionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

> **\b** --> Matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a
> character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (in either
> order). It cannot be used to separate non-words from words.
>
> **|** --> Equivalent to Boolean **OR**
>
> **?** --> matches a previous token between zero and one time, as many times as possible giving back as needed.

> **{3}** --> match previous regex 3 times
>
> **$**--> Matches the end of a string without consuming any characters. If multiline mode is used, this will also match immediately before a
> newline character.

```
 ((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$

\b character boundary
(\.|$) after the end of 3 digits, it can end the string and place a dot 
{3} repeat the previous string 3 times then move on to the last one

$ matches last character.
```

Comment: I can try my best but if you face any issues then tell me. I can take a reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp  but the answer with verified tick also has an issue, it can accept this value too. 10.10.10.10. also verify the last dot so i can make a new one hope it will help you.