# how to use python's reqular expression to match ip?

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to match the pattern of an IP address. what I have is
[0-999]*.[0-999]*.[0-999]*.[0-999]*
what test data are: 10.37.255.1 , 1.1.1.10 , and 2.2.3.3.3. Unfortunately it picks up the first 2 data sets as well as the first 4 numbers of the third data.
what can I do to exclude the third data set in the return?

[image]

Comment: First, ip address don't use `0 - 999` they go up to `255`. Nevertheless, a regex is not a great way to do this ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp) ).. You are probably better off using the builtin [ip address module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround your regex pattern by whitespace lookarounds:

```py
inp = "These are my IP addresses 10.37.255.1 and 1.1.1.10 and this is my serial and ID number 4.1.2, 2.2.3.3.3"
ips = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?!\S)', inp)
print(ips)  # ['10.37.255.1', '1.1.1.10']
```

Side note: `[0-999]` does *not* match the numbers 1 to 999.  Instead, it is identical to `[1-9]`, which matches any single number from 1 to 9.

Comment: I know they are just trying to find numbers separated by dots, but this is not a good solution for anyone finding this in the future. It matches invalid ip address like `980.37.255.1` and `10090.0.0.1`

Comment: @Mark My answer will extract all valid 4 part IP addresses.  As for _validating_ those IP addresses, the OP may consider the options given in your comment.