# check element in list and return a value and store in another list

Tags: python

I am trying to identify few IP accordingly, the requirement as below:

- There is a list of IP called ip_addresses.
- There is a list of registered IP called registered_list.
- There is a list of banned IP called banned_list.

1. If the element in ip_addresses in registered_list, return 1 and store in another list.
2. If the element in ip_addresses in banned_list, return 2 and store in another list.
3. If the element in ip_addresses in not in list and incorrect format, return 3 and store in another list.
4. If the element in ip_addresses in not in list and correct format, return 4 and store in another list.

My code as below:

```
ip_addresses = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.0","255.255.255.255","193.144.222.889"]
registered_list = ["192.168.0.1","123.123.123.123"]
banned_list = ["255.255.255.255"]

# Return answer[] as below
# 0 - Initial
# 1 - Registered
# 2 - Banned
# 3 - Wrong format
# 4 - Correct format but not registered

answer = []
def solution(ip_addresses, registered_list, banned_list):

    for ip_ID in ip_addresses: 

        # check ip_ID in register list
        for reg_ID in registered_list:
            if ip_ID==reg_ID:
                check=1     # if ip_ID in register list
                answer.append(check)

        # check ip_ID in banned list        
        for ban_ID in banned_list:
            if ip_ID==ban_ID:
                check=2     # if ip_ID in banned list
                answer.append(check)

        # if ip_ID not in being processed in registered and banned list        
        if check == 0:
            split=ip.split(".") # split ip into 4 elements             

            # check numbering for each element
            for spl_ID in split:
                if (
                    int(spl_ID)<= 255 and len(spl_ID)==3 or  
                    int(spl_ID)<= 100 and len(spl_ID)==2 or
                    int(spl_ID)<= 10 and len(spl_ID)==1
                    ):
                    check=4     # if all element correct
                    answer.append(check)
                else:
                    check=3     # either one of the element incorrect
                    answer.append(check)
    return answer
```

it only return the value [1,2] instead of [1,4,2,3]

[image]

May i know why my code stop flowing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you are using `check` variable in loop and don't reset it. So after first iteration your `check` variable already have value equal 1, because of logic of your code and first from `ip_addresses` list in `registered_list` list.
To fix this, set check to 0 in the beginning of every iteration:

```
for ip_ID in ip_addresses: 
    check = 0
    ...
```

btw you will get a error, because here

```
if check == 0:
    split=ip.split(".") # split ip into 4 elements
```

you are using `ip` variable which is not defined. I think you should rename it as `ip_ID`.

Anyway this code won't pass this task. If you want, i can try provide my solution.

**Strongly recommended to use debug mode to understand what is really happening in your code.**
**Also read [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)**

p.s. is it from codewars?

## My solution

```
def solution(ip_addresses, registered_list, banned_list):
    from re import fullmatch
    answer = []
    for ip in ip_addresses:
        if ip in registered_list:
            answer.append(1)
        elif ip in banned_list:
            answer.append(2)
        elif not fullmatch(r'^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$', ip):
            answer.append(3)
        elif fullmatch(r'^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$', ip):
            answer.append(4)
    return answer
```

stdout:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your guide. This question from my friend, i not sure where he get it from. Btw can u explain more on the pattern ? r'^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$'

Comment: @ChunSeong you are welcome. To be honest i just took it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp). I understand logic of this pattern, but i couldn't describe you every char. I spent hours learning regex :) Btw you method is also should work