# REG EXp for not http https but fqdn and also ip

Tags: regex

the text is

"I open https://my.javac.com/abcd/efgh/khj for 10.9.14.5 my.supernova.javavpn.com for uptime and text gathering and connect by ssh root@javavpn.com"

Now from this text my regexp will only take `10.9.14.5` the ip and `my.supernova.javavpn.com`

not https:// http://

I tried below but not works

```
!\b(https:\/\/.*)|(\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3})|([-a-zA-z0-9_.]+[.][c|C][o|O][m|M])
```

Comment: What do you *want* to match?

Comment: I want the ip and fqdn only from this text not any url like http://https://

Comment: So you *don't* want the `https://my.javac.com`?

Comment: I put your text and regex in here and it seems to exactly match what you want it to: https://regexr.com/7l44q - all IPs and FQDNs

Comment: yes I do not want @Nick

Comment: @ChrisBarr it select `https://my.javac.com` and also any where javac.com it select all so it is not accepted

Comment: I think it would be better to combine two regexes with post-processing, rather than trying to cram everything into one giant ugly regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you could use this regex:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\b|(?<![\w@\/.-])[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+
```

This matches either:

- `\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\b` : an IPv4 address preceded and followed by a word break
- `(?<![\w@\/.-])[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+` : a two or more level domain name (consisting of groups of `a-zA-Z0-9_-` characters, separated by a `.`), *not* preceded by a character in the set or `a-zA-Z0-9_/@.-`)

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tz9IoW/1)

Note that the IPv4 part of the regex will match illegal addresses e.g. `300.999.567.432`; if you don't want that, you can make use of regexes such as those in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp).