# sed command doesn't output properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm stuck in using sed command.
I try to get my network address using sed command.
My host is like

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.11.12
```

I want to get only "192.168.11." from the address above.
I tried

```
hostname -I | sed -E  's/([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3}.)([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3})$/\1\2\3/'
```

But it doesn't work and I get

```
192.168.11.12
```

Even though

```
echo "192.168.11.12" | sed -E  's/([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3}.)([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3})$/\1\2\3/'
```

works properly.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

My environment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Maybe there are extra characters after the "12".  Why do you match until end of line, instead of just matching at beginning of line?

Comment: It seems that you like to do something similar to [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760050/6771046), but for `{3}` instead of `{4}`.

Comment: `hostname -I` can give a list of IP addresses. So it appends a space behind each IP as separator, even if only one address is printed.

Comment: select what you desired: `hostname -I | grep -oP '^(\d{1,3}\.){3}'`  or delete unwanted: `hostname -I | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,3}$//'`

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understand what was wrong with me. Your comments were very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

@Wiimm already gave a comment with an explanation: the line ends with a space.
You can look at `echo "<$(hostname -I)>"`, the response will end with  `>`.

When you know you always get exactly one IP-address, you can use
`hostname -i | cut -d '.' -f1,3`.

What do you want, when the response can be `1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 1.2.4.1` ?

```
# Show the substring from the first address
echo '1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 1.2.4.1 ' | cut -d '.' -f1-3
1.2.3

# Show all sub-addresses (you can `| sort -u` when you want to)
$ echo '1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 1.2.4.1 ' | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -d '.' -f1-3
1.2.3
1.2.3
1.2.4

# Other way to show the three sub-addresses
$ echo '1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 1.2.4.1 ' | grep -Eo '[^ .]*\.[^ .]*\.[^ .]*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating things.

```
hostname -I |
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

as in, remove the last dot and all the text after it.

The immediate problem with your attempt seems to have been the missing backslash before one dot, and/or the lack of a line-beginning anchor; though neither of those would be fatal if it weren't for the fact that there is apparently some invisible text (a space? Or some control character?) at the end of the `hostname` output. Maybe pipe it to `cat -v` or `od -tx1` to see exactly what it prints.