# How to check validation of IP Address in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to add  IP Validation in my project .Is there any function in jquery or in jquery mobile.So that it will validate the in put field?

Thanks

Comment: You should be looking for `regular expressions`

Comment: Do some basic research before asking a question. Check this out https://gist.github.com/bcoughlan/2649187

Comment: I need only validate ip..Like we DO IN PHONE NUMBER..tEXT

Comment: i working on juery mobile with phonegap ..only validate Ip address to .User not right text .user only able to write Number with dots

Comment: [Here](http://www.google.nl/?q=javascript+validate+ip+address)'s your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

refer this document
[IP validation](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/04/validate-ip-address-using-jquery.html#.Ud8U1zs3sUJ)

here he has used jqueryvalidator.js and explained with an example.

```
            $.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
                return value.match(/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/);
            }, 'Invalid IP address');

            $('#form1').validate({
                rules: {
                    ip: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi your mask does not work please try this one /^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/;

Comment: Not working correctly. Mask is not correct. Check:  https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html

Answer (score 5):

The short version:

```
^(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$
```

Explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445549/3356679

Comment: Thank you, this comes with full details and explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions to test if an IP is valid:

```
"127.0.0.1".match(/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/);
```

Comment: doesn't really validate an ip: "999.0.0.1".match(/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/);

Comment: @Rohit Reason is right, that's not a valid IP. But you get the idea, you might need a more involved regex if you want to test for valid IPs

Answer (score 2):

This should work for IP address

```
$.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {

    var ip="^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
        return value.match(ip);
    }, 'Invalid IP address');

    $('#remoteForm').validate({
        rules: {
            ipAddr: {
                required: true,
                IP4Checker: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is the best Solution and Mask for IP Adress

```
$.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
        var ip = /^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/; 
        return value.match(ip);
        }, 'Invalid IP address');

    var $validator = $("#addCardForm").validate({
          rules: {
              txtIP: {
              required: true,
              IP4Checker: true
              }

          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery Validation Plugin by:

```
$.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
        var ip = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
            return value.match(ip);
}, 'Invalid IP address');

$('#form').validate({
    rules:{
        ip:{
            required: true,
            IP4Checker: true
        }
    }
});
```

Hope helpful.

Refer to: [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Comment: you copied it from best answer

Comment: i don't think so, see the regex. "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
    validIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
    validHostnameRegex = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
*/
$.validator.addMethod('ipChecking', function(value) {
    //var ip = "^(?:(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}" +"(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";
    validIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
    ipCheckFlag = true;
    ipLists = value.split(',');
    for(ip=0; ip<ipLists.length; ip++){
        if(!ipLists[ip].trim().match(validIpAddressRegex)){
            ipCheckFlag = false;
        }
    }
    return ipCheckFlag;     
});
```

[link](http://www.jayakumar.xyz/2017/02/how-to-check-validation-of-ip-address-in-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

Addition to answer by @RAVI MONE for IP address with subnet mask:

```
$.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
    var ip="^$|([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
      "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
      "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
      "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])((/([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))?)$";
    return value.match(ip);
}, 'Invalid IP address.');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns `true` if IP address is in correct format otherwise it returns `false`:

```
function isIpAddressValid(ipAddress) {
    if (ipAddress == null || ipAddress == "")
        return false;
    var ip = '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}' +
        '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$';
    if (ipAddress.match(ip) != null)
        return true;
}
```