# Regular Expression for hostname & ip

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a regex to validate IP-Addresses and one for Hostnames in Javascript.

I looked at many posts here and elsewhere but cannot quite find one that suits my needs.

For the IP I found two that work fine (dont know if there are differences other than the format):

1: (this is my preferred regex for IP-Addresses)

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

2:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

For the Hostname I found this one:

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/
```

which also works fine.

BUT^^ the problem is that the hostname regex will validate

```
192.168.178.1111
```

This is not a hostname, this is an invalid IP-Address.

I would like to fit both hostname & IP regex together in a single regex term but since the hostname regex will validate any non-valid IP-Address I cannot combine them.

Does anyone have an idea on how to create a hostname regex that will not validate an invalid IP-Address?

EDIT: I found this one as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/opd1v7au/2/

but this will validate for example:

```
::2:3:4:5
```

which my application cannot accept.

---

**Solution:** thx to [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron) I have this regex for now which seems to work (in testing at the moment)

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

Combined version to validate IP-Addresses & Hostnames [->RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/3dt4r):

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$|^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check validation of IP Address in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587994/how-to-check-validation-of-ip-address-in-jquery)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address

Comment: those either work for IP only which I already have 2 working ones or do not work correctly on hostnames. Something like IP-Regex is shown as valid which is wrong. And you cannot combine IP & Hostname together to work correctly

Comment: ipv4 or ipv6 ip addresses ? `::2:3:4:5` is a valid ipv6 address (`0000:0000:0000:0000:0002:0003:0004:0005`)

Comment: ipv4 for the moment. This may be the case but my application will not accept this kind of notation

Comment: I don't know why it shoud be [a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-] rather than [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this SU answer](https://serverfault.com/a/638270/137546), I propose this modification, which accepts labels starting with digits except for the top level domain :

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/
```

Comment: it does work for some hostnames, but it will also validate something like `IP-REGEX` or `Sample`

Comment: Which are valid hostnames, according to rfc1035, as is `localhost` ; what problem do you have with them?

Comment: Maybe would you want them to end with a 2-3 letters TLD?

Comment: they are valid? that seems odd. I would have expected there hast to be at least a dot in it like test.domain or test.tld or something like that

Comment: If you want at least 2 labels, change your first `*` into a `+`. It should be ok with "Internet domains" since they are all under TLDs. A well known example of 1-label domain name is `localhost`.

Comment: the regex provided doesn't match 100.com, which is a valid hostname

Comment: I was about to say that `localhost` is the only 1 word domain that I would consider  valid^^ I changed the **second** `*` into a `+` and now it seems to be working. Im going to run some tests with possible hostnames against it.

Comment: @Alkahna you can define custom domain names in your `/etc/host` file, and nothing restricts you from making them 1 word long. Your sysadmin could also expose some on your DNS server, although I don't think it's common practice

Comment: @Alkahna I've edited the regex, looks like labels can start by digits, except when they're top domain. You should use the updated one

Comment: I rather go with "do not start with digit" as this will not be the case for any hostname that will be used in my case ;) This way I can combine hostname & ip which is ideal

Comment: @Aaron I doubt Alkahna writes an rfc checker. I guess they want to check hostnames, that exist in reality. You still can distinguish them from invalid ip-addresses, since the root zone can't contain digits.

Comment: your updated regex term looks good. I did change the the second `*` into a `+` though to prevent hostnames like `sample` or `regex-test` to be valid

Comment: @enkryptor Weill hostnames should follow RFCs, just not the outdated one I was reading. Thanks for pointing out my shortcoming

Comment: may it help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address/3824105#3824105