# JavaScript regex on textarea input

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract all IP addresses from an Apache log file input in the textarea field. I am using regular expressions for extracting the IP addresses. I want to see all the IP addresses printed on the screen.
I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Kindly help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>RegEx_example</title>
</head>
<body style = "background-color: lightgrey">
<center>
<h3><u>Log Miner</u></h3>
<br /><hr />
<h5>Paste your Apache log file in the box below and click on Mine!</h5>

<textarea  rows="25" cols="200" form="mine_log" id = "logs">

</textarea>

<form id = "mine_log" method = "" onsubmit="parseLogs(document.getElementById('logs').value)">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Mine!!" />
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function parseLogs(text) {
        var re = new RegExp("^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$");
        var myArray = re.exec("text");
        document.write(myArray.toString());

    }
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what issue are you having with the code now?

Comment: You surely need to try a regex literal `var re = /([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})/g;`. And use `input.match(re)`.

Comment: @Reddy : it is not displaying anything. It should print all the occurrences of the addresses

Comment: You're testing string "test"  instead of given variable

Comment: Remove `^`anchors`$`.

Comment: Add `g` modifier.

Comment: Double-backslashes required for regex strings. Alternative: use `/`literal`/`

Comment: Remove quotes from around variable name `"text"`

Comment: Acquire simple debugging skills.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26445549/2592042

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Your regex pattern worked. I guess mine was incorrect. Thanks

Comment: @AnuvratTiku: Glad to help. I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Use a regex literal to avoid double backslash escaping the shorthand classes (right now, `"\."` translates into `.`)
- Remove anchors from the pattern (i.e. the `^` and `$`)
- Add a global modifier to the regex (`/g`)
- Use a `String#match()` with the regex (in case you do not need the values captured with the capturing groups, else, you need to run the `RegExp#exec` inside a loop to collect those).

```js
function parseLogs(text) {
   var re = /([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})/g;
   var myArray = text.match(re);
   document.write("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(myArray, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
}
```

```html
<h5>Paste your Apache log file in the box below and click on Mine!</h5>

<textarea  rows="5" cols="200" form="mine_log" id = "logs">
12.34.56.76
 45.45.34.24
</textarea>
<form id = "mine_log" method = "" onsubmit="parseLogs(document.getElementById('logs').value)">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Mine!!" />
</form>
```

Note that in case you need no captured values, you may even remove the `(` and `)` from your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I see a typo in the code.

`var myArray = re.exec("text");` you are just running the regex on the **string** `text`

should be

`var myArray = re.exec(text);` run the regex on the **variable** `text`

Comment: Typos are not real issues.

Comment: That doesn't help, but there are at least two more problems.