# Validating IP address is not working in html javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have written a regex to validate `IP address` on input type = text but the below is not working.

```html
<label for="">Signet/DSC IP Address</label>
<span class="mandatory" style="color: red;">*</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSignDSCIPAdd" 
  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" />
```

Comment: You are not validating anything, you are just not allowing two dots next to eachother

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345/how-to-evaluate-an-ip

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating anything, you are just not allowing two dots next to each other

Here is a pattern that will validate the format but not the logic

Hit enter to validate the format 999.999.999.999

I then test the validity of each octet (cannot start with 0.0)

```js
const isValidOctet = (num, index) => num <= 255 && (index < 2 ? num >= 1 : num >= 0);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('txtSignDSCIPAdd').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    tgt.setCustomValidity('');
    const s = tgt.value.trim();
    const match = s.match(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$/);
    const valid = match != null &&
      isValidOctet(+match[1], 0) &&
      isValidOctet(+match[2], 1) &&
      isValidOctet(+match[3], 2) &&
      isValidOctet(+match[4], 3);
    if (match && !valid) {
      console.log(isValidOctet(match[0], valid, +match[1], 0), isValidOctet(+match[2], 1), isValidOctet(+match[3], 2), isValidOctet(+match[4], 3))
      tgt.setCustomValidity(`The entered IP address is not valid (match: ${match[0]}, valid: ${valid})`);
      tgt.reportValidity();
    }
  });
  // while testing
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    console.log('Submitted');
    e.preventDefault()
  })

});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="">Signet/DSC IP Address</label>
  <span class="mandatory" style="color: red;">*</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSignDSCIPAdd" pattern="\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" required/>
</form>
```